# Loops to break up a vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector

```
   A = [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 6 7 ]
```

and I was to write a line of code that will loop through the vector splitting it into two, after each unique value in the vector.
ex:

The first loops would give

```
A1 = [ 1 1 1 1 ]
A2 = [2 2 2 4 4 6 7 ]
```

the second loop would give

```
A1 = [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ] 
A2 =  [ 4 4 6 7 ]
```

and so on until the final vectors are

```
A1 = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 6]
A2 = [7]
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you HAVE to use loops?

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

```
A = [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 6 7 ];

solutions=0;
for i=1:size(A,2)
    j=i+1;
    if(j<=size(A,2))
        if(A(1,i)~=A(1,j))
            solutions=solutions+1;
            B1{solutions}(1,:)=A(1,1:i);
            B2{solutions}(1,:)=A(1,i+1:end);
        end
    end
end
```

The loop goes through the complete array and checks two adjacent entries for inequality. If they are, the sub-vectors are saved in two cell arrays. One for the first parts and one for all the second parts.

Answer (score 0):

Use differential method

```
A = [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 4 4 6 7 ]
D = A(1:end-1)==A(2:end)
B = find(D==0)
for ii = 1:length(B)
A1 = A(1:B(ii))     
A2 = A(B(ii)+1:end) 
end
```